# Ice cream jar of a given volume using calculus

Tags: calculus

Suppose an ice cream factory puts ice cream into cylindrical containers. The volume of ice cream in each container is $233π$ cubic inches. What is the least amount of material required to make one container (include a simple lid for the top of the container)? Round your answer to the nearest square inch.

I started by using the formula $$V=(\pi)r^2*h$$ and I plugged in $233\pi$ for the volume and solved for $h$ I got $$h=\frac{233}{r^2}$$ then I plugged it into the surface area of a cylinder formula getting $$A=2*\pi*r(\frac{233}{r^2})+2*\pi*r^2$$ I took the derivative and set it equal to $0$ getting $$0=\frac{-466*\pi}{x^2}+4*\pi*x$$ and I got $$x=\frac{233}{2}^\frac{1}{3}$$ I plugged this back into the original equation for $A$ and got $500$ after rounding can anyone give me some advice for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

> Notice:
>
> - $$\text{Volume cylinder}=\pi r^2h$$
> - $$\text{Surface area cylinder}=2\pi r(r+h)$$

---

So, for the given volume:

$$\text{Volume cylinder}=233\pi\to\pi r^2h=233\pi\Longleftrightarrow hr^2=233\Longleftrightarrow h=\frac{233}{r^2}$$

So, for the surface area:

$$\text{Surface area cylinder}=2\pi r(r+h)=2\pi r\left(r+\frac{233}{r^2}\right)=\frac{2\pi(r^3+233)}{r}$$

Now, solve $\frac{\text{d}\text{Surface area cylinder}}{\text{d}r}=0$ for $r$ (only the real solution) to get the minimum:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}\left(\frac{2\pi(r^3+233)}{r}\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow-\frac{2\pi(233-2r^3)}{r^2}=0\Longleftrightarrow r=\sqrt[3]{\frac{233}{2}}\approx4.884$$

And for $h$ we get:

$$h=\frac{233}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{233}{2}}\right)^2}=2^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{233}\approx9.767$$

**EDIT:**

A plot of the problem shows you where the smallest $r$ is:

[image: Plot]

Comment: so when i plug r and h into the surface area formula i got 500 which is wrong. am i missing something?

Comment: @sammy Yes, round about 500, that's the smallest amound of material you need to make the pakkage for the ice cream]

Comment: Its saying 500 is wrong

Comment: @sammy What is it saying it shoud be? I don't see what I did wrong (if I did that)

Comment: i dont know what the answer is supposed to be. i tried 499 and 500. i just cant see how any other answer could be right

Comment: The exact surface area equals $3\pi\cdot\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot233^{\frac{2}{3}}\approx449.626$. So it is not $500$

Comment: it says round to the nearest inch

Comment: @sammy I checked it again, my answer is right! I'm sure

Comment: The minimum surface area is $$S = 2\pi r(r + h) = 2\pi \sqrt[3]{\frac{233}{2}}\left[\sqrt[3]{\frac{233}{2}} + \frac{233}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\frac{233}{2}}\right)^2}\right] \approx 449.626334668$$ cubic inches, as Jan Eerland found.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, exactly what I said :)

Comment: @JanEerland  That was the point I was trying to make, but I was distracted by a typographical error I made.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig It's oke. I'm sure I got the right answer!